# Please don't use emojis in official e-mail subjects

Tags: feature-request, old-teams, email

I just opened my inbox to find this:

> [image]
> [image]

This is supposedly an e-mail from the Stack Overflow Teams beta program, but due to the emojis in the title I almost immediately clicked "Spam", due to the large amounts of emails having emojis in their title belonging to that category.

I don't think its useful nor necessary to have icons in the subject, and can often times be mistaken for spam. It also looks horrible most of the time as pointed out by @AdamLear. The only upside is looking cool, but I don't think the benefits outweigh the drawbacks. In my opinion, this practice should be avoided in the future.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Thank you sharing your thoughts. The decision to use emojis was deemed permissible for the following reasons:

1. They can help people more quickly clarify the email's subject *and* a tone we're trying to set.
2. We wanted all email recipients to understand that this wasn't some urgent request, but a friendly request to take a survey (that would truly help us).
3. As the email was sent to a subset of the Teams private beta group, we deemed it more permissible to employ the use of emojis than we would in a larger announcement.

Speaking more broadly, Stack Overflow uses little bits of fun like this throughout many of its communications. Examples are images like these on our 404 error pages:

[image]
[image]

…or used videos like this to announce a brand change…

[image]

We used emojis to get the email recipients attention and hopefully interest them to help us out by taking a survey (which would be very helpful to us!). This email received a very high open (80%+) and click-through rate (60%+).

The idea that people would react poorly to the emojis didn't even cross my mind. It was a small attempt to insert some light-heartedness into a rather dull, boring request; to be "business up front, party in the back" with our email subject lines.

[image]

---

**Note:** This has been edited from the original. No new information was added beyond updating the email's success rate. The edits made were in the framing of the post, re-writing the sarcastic tone I had originally taken. While I did it in jest, some correctly pointed out that the tone I took could be seen as demeaning and passive-aggressive. That isn't my intention. Only to dryly make a point. However, that isn't needed. So I apologize to **DJDavid** and any others who took offense. I pray you can forgive the transgression. Thank you.

Comment: To be honest it's not you who misuse it, it's the spammers. But consider this example: if `window.open` without user interaction wouldn't be blocked by default, many websites could easily bombard users with annoying popups. Sites that could have used it for legitimate reasons were also blocked the same way as the bad guys, without the intention of doing harm. It's a distant example, but simply put, in my personal opinion, if you're going to use something that spammers also use on a regular basis, you might end up being treated as a spammer despite your intentions. Sorry if I was a bit harsh.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks for letting us know. 

Comment: Forget the emojis. Let's talk about your *photoshop* abuse. While I support your "biz up front; party out back" ethos, I CANNOT support this unauthorized use of my likeness to convey it. You'll be hearing from my hair lawyer.

Comment: @Jaydles This picture is the gift that keeps on giving.

Comment: Related: [How to auto-delete messages with animated emoji in the subject in Gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89119)

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick, but how does a smiling face with sunglasses help anyone "more quickly clarify the email's subject"? Also, for what it's worth, I'm not sure that unicorn video went over terribly well either.

Comment: @KyleStrand Too true. It was very insulting to unicorns.

Comment: A smiley face wearing sunglasses does not "help people more quickly clarify the email's subject".  This sarcastic official-account response is inappropriate as you're asking people to donate their time on testing a feature no one from the community _even seems to want_ and then you're are throwing 'tude at feedback.  C'mon @Hynes, I know you work for the monopoly in the programming Q&A space, but treat your users with respect.  Don't be passive-aggressive by saying things like "on-brand", just take the 5 minutes to properly express yourself in your emails.

Comment: Some people are just complainers. Emoji in email subject is fine and I actually like these little things that you do to try and seem a bit more casual.

Comment: can't speak english today, so meant to edit this in: Which is to say, if you want to use emojis in your communications, fine, whatever.  My problem is your disrespectful and trivializing tone in responding to DJDavid and the people that are agreeing with him/her.  I can't _ever_ imagine being as passive aggressive to the users of my startup as you were in the content before "All kidding aside,".  Even the unprofessional bullshit 'tude you used to try to shift from acknowledging my points suggests you have no place being near users.

Comment: Cool, great, good to know that the full lifecycle of features no-one-in-the-community-wants is on par with the quality of support they'll receive post-release. :) (used an emoji so others would know that this message is fun-loving and not an annoyed demarcation of this stressful exchange)

Comment: @tristan Thinking about this some more, you have a point. In retrospect, I shouldn't have responded the way I did. Responses like that aren't always taken as intended. My intent isn't to demean, but that doesn't come through clearly to all when using sarcasm. There is no ill intent on my part, but—again—that's not how some people took it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @tristan I edited the post based on your comments. Once again, sorry for the offense. Thank you for taking the time to call me out on it. No one likes being told their wrong, but you were right. I need to humble myself and accept that.

Comment: It's all good, even if I do seem like a berating jerk with your comments removed from the thread.

Comment: @tristan Nah. You're fine. One comment was removed by someone else and the other I removed after re-reading it. I didn't see you had responded to it until after I had deleted the comment. Once again — thanks for pointing out where I could be a better person.

Comment: @Hynes I seem to have missed out on some comments that lead to the edits made & comments deleted, but I personally didn't take this answer in its original form as an insult whatsoever.

Comment: One danger with using emoji, @Hynes, is that they can look drastically different depending on the device used. http://mentalfloss.com/article/70879/9-emojis-look-completely-different-other-phones Or worse, you innocently use an emoticon like an eggplant and some water droplets, not realizing they have sexual connotations!

Answer (score -11):

Honestly the @stackoverflow.com  was a dead giveaway it was stackoverflow most modern messaging clients will detect spoofed emails.

Personally I think emojis should be utilized since that's how many services interact with their audience, for example you can order a pizza with  emoji.

I like the fact emails or messages can be spruced up with out the need for lots of HTML and images. It makes for a small email download and gets the context of the email across to the recipient.   ✌