# Replace kiddie text-speak with proper English words

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Apparently, the profile page has the following options for "career":

- Work
- School
- Just <3 code

Let's replace the [confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307755/560648) and playground-esque final option with [Hans's suggestion of "Enthusiast"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317919/what-is-just-3-code#comment314980_317919).

Comment: But I »-(¯`·.·´¯)-> ASCII.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: "Enthusiast" is ASCII.

Comment: We should use one of these instead:      

Comment: @PreferenceBean ... art :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Okay how about [this](http://pastebin.com/jMeNnuJh) as a compromise?

Comment: @PreferenceBean I can now die in peace.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: RIP my friend.

Comment: "Enthusiast" works, but you can arguably code for a living and love it at the same time (both "Work" and "Enthusiast"). Perhaps "Hobbyist" would be a better substitute?

Comment: @CodyGray: Yeah, that's good too.

Comment: @balpha: You can keep them for your email subjects.

Comment: @bolt Email subjects? [Uh-oh](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315670/please-dont-use-emojis-in-official-e-mail-subjects).

Comment: Orrrrr we can destroy the three buttons that behave like radiobuttons but do not look like radiobuttons. Then, perhaps, we can either leave this out entirely or replace it with proper checkboxes.

Comment: @Will: Yes, because one hashtag used stylistically on a user profile is the same as a prominent UX feature on a professional programming Q&A being labelled "Just <3 code".

Comment: @Will: None of which has anything to do with the site proper. But thank you for coming on to this feature request with your constructive and not at all personal commentary. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sometimes we don't always know what kind of impressions we give to others.  I know what impressions I give (they usually start with an A or a D).  I'm just sharing the knowledge with you.  Good day to you, sir.

Comment: @Will Are you suggesting that we need to treat the UI/UX of SO like we would a personal profile page, or are you suggesting that we have to treat all personal profile pages like professional websites?

Comment: Boy, I don't want to tell you what I thought `<3` symbolizes...

Comment: @CodyGray: You can also be in school, work as a programmer, and program as a hobby outside of both work and school, all at the same time. I'm with StephanBijzitter here; they should definitely be checkboxes instead of radiobuttons.

Comment: Work, school, hobby - these words are on the same level.

Comment: Just asking: why? I think this suggestion should include some motivation as to why this should be done.

Comment: Who is actually bothered by this? I know this site attempts to be as professional as possible but things like that give it an interesting touch. Why not turn the whole site grayscale while we're at it?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck [Several](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317919/what-is-just-3-code?lq=1) [people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307751/currently-in-testing-improved-new-user-signup-expanded-profile-information/307755#307755) have expressed confusion as to its meaning.

Comment: @IMSoP Just googling for [<3](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%3C3) would give them a lovely definition though

Comment: Googling for answers yourself instead of asking any random question that pops up is not in the spirit of Stack Overflow lately. @MXD

Comment: Requiring Google to understand a user interface is bad design. It is just not a commonly understood symbol (yet).

Comment: @IMSoP: If it's confusing there should be a justification for changing it based on that, not the rather insulting dismissal of it as "kiddie text speak" and "playground-esque." The way in which this is phrased is enough for an automatic "No" from me. Is there something wrong with fun? Who defines what is "professional"? A previous generation's stodginess need not define this for everyone. Further, "Enthusiast" and "Hobbyist" are not adequate alternatives. If you want to change it I suggest "I just love code" because that is approximately the same meaning.

Comment: @Sorpigal A very well-made point, and I agree with everything you've said in that comment. (While still thinking the "<3" is ugly and confusing.)

Comment: @Sorpigal: On the contrary, seeing a button labelled "Just <3 code" _is_ insulting, because we're _not_ kiddies, the SO UX is not an SMS conversation, and nobody here is in the playground (well, presumably?).

Comment: @PreferenceBean And I believe that was precisely the crux of his comment; your statement that text emoji belong in the playground are entirely subjective, not to mention insulting to people who belong to a culture where "text speak" is appropriate to use in informal conversation. Because the real issue is about representation, not meaning, right? If it were "I \*symbol of a heart\* code", would it still be infantile and "not proper enough"?

Comment: Just to add to the radio buttons/check boxes argument I'm a programming apprentice meaning that I have a job where I code and then have to go to college one day a week to learn about it as well. ....I also code in my spare time :)

Comment: I agree with @Sorpigal, to think that option is insulting is really subjective, it goes along the lines of thinking everyone should wear a suit in the work environment. And although I don't really like the so called "text-speak", I do agree with Sorpigal that "Enthusiast" or "Hobbyist" don't convey the same meaning. When I see "Just <3 code" I actually think of child-like wonder and enthusiasm for code, which may, very much be what an employer is looking for. (Maybe that option could have a tool-tip translating the "text-speak" to proper English to avoid confusion)

Comment: Some people are taking things WAY too seriously. I could agree that `<3` could be confusing, but considering it "insulting and playground-esque" is completely exaggerated.

Comment: Guys let's keep the argumentative commentary to a minimum please. The feature request is clear.

Comment: @PreferenceBean *You* bring this with this tone, I think your feature request will be much more audible if you would have spare the disrespectful adjectives and bring this matter in a less subjective way.

Comment: How about "Just 3< code"

Comment: I'm curious...where does this actually show up on the profile page?  I can't find it on mine...

Comment: @brandaemon It's on the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab, under "Career" > "Where do you code?".

Comment: @MikeM. I know but does it show up on the public profile anywhere?

Comment: @brandaemon Oh, I getcha. You're being rhetorical. Sorry, I'm a little, let's say, obtuse, atm.